# Audio data API beat detection

Tags: api, audio, fft

I'm working with Mozilla Audio Data API, following instructions [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API#Complete_Example%3a_Visualizing_Audio_Spectrum).

The code above is using `Float32Array` in FFT algorithm. It seems to hold the frequence variation that is later stocked in `magnitude`. I would like to make a condition to determine if that number is bigger than 1, like so :

```
if (magnitude > 1) {
  beat = true;
} else {
  beat = false;
}
```

That condition fails, do you have any idea why ?
Thanks.

Comment: What size of FFT are you using? In general, FFTs are a poor choice for beat detection because it lacks temporal resolution.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by size of FFT ? I just consider using this API is easier for me because I don't have great algo skills...

Comment: It's a big deal.  FFTs operate on windows of samples. By definition, the time resolution of any algorithm trying to do onset detection with an FFT is the period of this window - and in practice, less.  If you were operate with a 1024pt FFT, this gives a resolution at 44.1kHz of 23ms - which put another way, a 43th of a second.  Practical onset detection algorithms tend to be not be based in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 0):

You conditional test may fail for a variety of reasons.  The scale of the magnitude might be wrong for a threshold of 1.  You may be looking at the wrong magnitude.  Or the type of music you are testing may have beats that do not change that magnitude enough to cross your threshold reliably.

There exist university research papers on the subject of beat detection that you might find useful to read.

Comment: I would second reading academic literature on the subject.  You might also checkout out Sonic Visualiser too - which has included various onset-detection modules. A fundamental problem with spectral approaches to onset detection is that many onsets in popular music are from percussive sounds which tend to resemble noise - energy splatted across a wide range of frequencies.